# How to make a intersect in SOLR?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

I am implementing a solr project, with the structure below of my indexed object.

```js
{
  "OBJECT_HEADER_ID": 173604,
  "CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID": 143287,
  "OBJECT_TYPE_ID": 1,
  "SEQUENCE": 0,
  "CHARACTERISTIC_ID": 1488,
  "OBJECT_VARIANT_ID": 169941,
  "ID": "84445897",
  "TYPE": 0
},
{
  "OBJECT_HEADER_ID": 173604,
  "CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID": 23502,
  "OBJECT_TYPE_ID": 1,
  "SEQUENCE": 0,
  "CHARACTERISTIC_ID": 992,
  "OBJECT_VARIANT_ID": 169941,
  "ID": "84445898",
  "TYPE": 0
}
```

And I need to make a intersect between various results in sub queries, and I don't found nothing on the WEB about how to make the query, for example:
-> Get all results that have (CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 1488 and CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID = 143287) INTERSECT BY OBJECT_VARIANT_ID WITH (CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 992 and CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID = 23502).

Comment: So "get a document that has *char_id = 1488, char_value = 143287* and that has an *obj_variant_id that is common* with a document that has *char_id = 992 and char_value = 23502*? (I'm not familiar with "intersect by")

Comment: Like to make the query in SQL: SELECT V.ID
FROM OBJECT_VARIANT V
WHERE V.OBJECT_TYPE_ID = 1
AND V.ID IN (
  SELECT O.OBJECT_VARIANT_ID ID
    FROM OBJECT_VALUE O
    WHERE O.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 1488 AND O.CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID = 143287
INTERSECT
  SELECT O.OBJECT_VARIANT_ID ID
    FROM OBJECT_VALUE O
    WHERE O.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 992 AND O.CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID = 23502
);

Comment: Yes, I saw your query - As I stated, I'm not familiar with what "INTERSECT" does (as it seems to be a MSSQL extension?). Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: Ok, I solved using another strategy, SOLR does not support intersect like sql. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your "another strategy", Thanks.

Comment: I created the filter in memory, intersecting various queries in application side.